# Why do we need to define a function to call another function?

Tags: python, pytorch

In the [implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/resnet.py) of ResNet architecture in Pytorch I encountered the code below which is from line 264 til 283:

```
def _forward_impl(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    # See note [TorchScript super()]
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.maxpool(x)

    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    x = self.layer4(x)

    x = self.avgpool(x)
    x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
    x = self.fc(x)

    return x

def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    return self._forward_impl(x)
```

What is the purpose of `_forward_impl`? Why didn't the coder bring what is happening inside `_forward_impl` into `forward` itself and getting ride of `_forward_impl`? I see `_forward_impl` looks like a private method, since it has underscore at the start of its name, however, I cannot yet see what the purpose of `_forward_impl` is.

Comment: It's apparently necessary for [subclassing](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/e8dded4c05ee403633529cef2e09bf94b07f6170/torchvision/models/mobilenetv2.py#L190)

Comment: here's a deeper explanation: https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/developers/13.1/catfilecreationreferenceguide/inheritance.html

Comment: Please read and abide by tag wiki descriptions.